# How to run a salesforce batch file from command line

Tags: data-loader

We are using the command line dataloader for data migration to salesforce. How can I call the batch file from command line (Facilities.bat) which is in folder c:\users\administrators\salesforce.com\Dataloader\Facilities? I need to debug the error why it is not inserting the records to salesforce what is the best approach. I have the config files, process-config.xml, mapping and encrypt passwords where I can find the exact error? it has been scheduled using the windows scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure process-conf.xml file for:-

1. SOAP logging - enable by:-

   <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="false"/>
   <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="c:\users\administrators\salesforce.com\Dataloader\salesforce_debug.log"/>
2. Error logging -

   <entry key="process.outputError" value="c:\users\administrators\salesforce.com\Dataloader\import_error.csv"/>

For more details refer:-https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=loader_params.htm